# Mi selfbot solo responde a mi y no a otros usuarios

Tags: python, discord.py

El usuario que ejecuta el codigo si le responde los comandos como enviar "xd" y le responde "lmao", pero a los demás no, como puedo hacer que todos pueden usar los comandos del selfbot

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

#TOKEN
TOKEN = "u token"

client = discord.Client()
b = Bot(command_prefix = "x")

@b.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I ready")

@b.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "xd":
        await message.channel.send("lmao")

b.run(TOKEN, bot = False)
```